# updating a queryset throws an error upon iteration in python/django

Tags: python, django

I have an ordered query that I want to append to a list and then split into sublists based on the price. My code is as follows:

```
def home(books):

grouped_books = []

for i in range(len(books) - 1):
    this_book = books[i].price
    next_book = books[i+1].price

    if this_book != next_book and price >= 100:
        r = books[:i+1]
        grouped_books.append(r)
        for ob in grouped_books:
           books = books.exclude(id__in=[o.id for o in ob])
```

Upon iterating after the query is updated, this code throws an error that `list index is out of range`

Am I doing something wrong here? I'd appreciate your help.
Thanks!

Comment: A `QuerySet` is not a list. So `books[:i+1]` will create a *new* queryset. Furthermore you use `books = books.exclude(..)`, so that means that after an iteration the length of the `books` has changed. The `range(..)` only evaluates the length of the `books` *once* before starting the iteration.

Comment: Can you explain exactly *what* you aim to do? Right now it is hard to propose a more elegant solution.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem 
`books = Books.objects.filter(added_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('price')`
This is my query to retrieve some objects. All the books that have price less than 100 are to be computed further. While, those that have price more than 200 , and 300 are to be computed differently, respectively. So, I want to make a list that can take sublists of these objects

Comment: then you can make use of `groupby`.

Answer (score 0):

A `QuerySet` is not a list. So using `books[:i+1]` makes not much sense. Furthermore you *alter* `books`. Indeed, you write `books = books.exclude(…)`. This thus means that if you reduce the number of elements in the `books` queryset, the index will eventually go out of range. Note that the `range(len(books) - 1)` part is only evaluated at the *beginning* of the `for` loop. It is thus not updated.

I think however you make things too complicated. You can make a query where you order the books by `price`, and then use [**`groupby(…)`** [Python-doc]](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import attrgetter

def home(books):
    return [
        list(vs)
        for __, vs in groupby(books.order_by('price'), attrgetter('price'))
    ]
```

or if you want to group per price range of 100:

```
from itertools import groupby

def home(books):
    return [
        list(vs)
        for __, vs in groupby(books.order_by('price'), lambda b: b.price // 100)
    ]
```